# What collection to use here

Tags: java, collections

I'm wondering what collection I should use for this purpose:

**Requirements**

1. Must contain tuples `<value1,value2>`
2. There is not relation between those values (no key-value pairs)
3. Can only contain unique tuples
4. `<value1,value2>` is equal to `<value2,value1>`

What would be best to use here?

Comment: take a loot at guava http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use any Set (HashSet, for instance). Create an object to represent your tuple and implement hashcode and equals properly.

Comment: Exactly.  The key to your last requirement (not caring about the order of the elements) is simply an implementation of `equals` that will work regardless of the order.

Comment: So there is no Map (or something like that) collection that doesn't have a relation between the two values?

Comment: A Map, by definition, is all about key-value pairs. An implementation that fails to do so is incorrect, failing to implement it's contract.

Comment: The bigger problem is that there is no tuple implementation in Java readily available AFAIK.

Comment: By definition, a Map implies a relationship between two objects.  Map is a mathematical term indicating a "if I have the key, I can find the target" relationship.  A Set has no relationship between elements, what you need is a set of tuples (pairs of two items).  You just need to write the code for the tuple (implementing equals and hashcode properly) and the Set will do the rest for you.

Comment: @Martin, you're right, there's not default Tuple class in java.  But even if there was, in this case it probably wouldn't matter, as I can't imagine a default Tuple class that implements (a,b) == (b,a).

Comment: @Edwin Yes that's another problem. I just think that the Map vs. Set issue is even more important here.

Answer (score 2):

Implement your own tuple class with [equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [hashCode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) as outlined below, then use [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

```
public class Tuple<T> {
    T v1;
    T v2;

    @override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (o instanceof Tuple) {
            return (v1.equals(o.v1) && v2.equals(o.v2))
                   || (v1.equals(o.v2) && v2.equals(o.v1));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @override
    public int hashCode() {
        // must produce a.hashCode() == b.hashCode() if a.equals(b)
        // example below may or may not work for your concrete equals()
        return v1.hashCode() ^ v2.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) appears to meet your criteria.  The Set would have to contain another collection or a custom object that contains the two values.